# Using Keypress and keydown for for firefox,chrome, and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keydown

Im using keydown and keypress, this code only working on chrome but not in firefox.
the 1st function is User can only use number, numpad, backspace and tab. Another function is, when user typing a number it will automatically change to decimal
default --> 0.00

enter 1 --> 0.01

enter 0 --> 0.10

enter 0 --> 1.00

You can find my demo
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hemiz/pYHDE/146/)

```
$('#txtInput').keydown(function(event) {

var Key = event.which;
//number
if (Key >= 48 && Key <= 57) {
    return true;
}
//numpad
else if (Key >= 96 && Key <= 105) {
    return true;
}
//backspace,tab
else if (Key >= 8 && Key <= 9) {
    return true;
}
else return false;
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtInput').keypress(function(e){
    var value = $('#txtInput').val().toString();
    var number = null;
    if(value == '')
        value = '0.00';
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 48:
        case 49:
        case 50:
        case 51:
        case 52:
        case 53:
        case 54:
        case 55:
        case 56:
        case 57:
            number = e.which - 48;
            break;
        default:
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
    }
    var dotIndex = value.indexOf('.');
    if(number === null)
    {
        value = value.substr(0,dotIndex-1) + '.' + value.substr(dotIndex -1,1) + value.substr(dotIndex+1,1);
        if(value.indexOf('.') ==0)
        {
            value = '0' + value;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        value = value.substr(0,dotIndex) + value.substr(dotIndex+1,1) + '.' + value.substr(dotIndex+2);

        value += number.toString();  
        value = value.replace(/^0+/,'');
        if(value.indexOf('.') == 0)
        {
            value = '0' + value;
        }               

    }
    $('#txtInput').val(value);
    e.preventDefault();
}).keypress(function(e){

    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 48:
        case 49:
        case 50:
        case 51:
        case 52:
        case 53:
        case 54:
        case 55:
        case 56:
        case 57:
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What FF version are you using?  I am using 13.0.1 and it is working great.

Comment: What version of Firefox does it not work on? I'm using version 12 and it appears to work fine. Do you see any errors in the Firebug console (do you have Firebug installed when testing)?

Comment: v13.0.1 . You can try by typing any number 1st, after that, enter letter. the value becoming zero.